# php session lost after submitting form

Tags: php, session, session-variables

The code below page keeps session on GET requests or refreshing browser, but when I submit a form the session data is lost.

```
$user=$_POST['user']; $pass=$_POST['pass'];
if ($_POST['user'])
{ if($user==$un and $pass=$pw)
  { $_SESSION['uid']=$Xid;header('Location: '.$uri.'?welcome'); }
  else { $msg="chybny login";  }
}

if(isset($_GET['logout']))   { session_destroy(); header('Location: '.$uri); }
$cnt=$_SESSION['cnt']+1; $_SESSION['cnt']=$cnt;
```

Above is the code for login which re-directs me to the welcome page as it was verified, however the session is lost. If I just refresh or repeatedly load the page without submitting, the session holds by echoing the session variable cnt (counts up 1,2,3,...)

After submitting the form, I see session is lost and too cnt variable is reset?

Comment: Sanity check: are you ever calling `session_start()`?

Comment: Where is `logout` being set to true? Agree with above poster, add more of your code. Don't assume you know where the error is.

Comment: logout is not set anywhere just future plan to add link with href="?logout"

Comment: session start is there, session works while pure GET requests

Comment: Well either your not calling `session_start();` where and as often as you should, or your destroying it some how.

Comment: Can we see some more code? Also, you don't have register_globals on perchance do you?

Comment: You don't just start the session once.  You have to place session_start(); at the beginning of every page you'd like to use your session variables.

Comment: Also, does you user-side POST clear cookies at all.

Comment: except session_start(); ob_start(); $un and $pw definition on beginning, a minimalistic login form and pure html wrapper there is nothing else in the file. Globals dont need to be registered as using superglobals _GET, _POST, .. only session destroy is the one in the if(logout) as seen in code... for now this is a mini code / one page only - and as hosted by small local as...les i am confident they have some misconfig in php ini... but what could that be?

Comment: On a side note, we can't devince the `php.ini` error, if that's what you think is wrong then post that code.  Ask your real question `What in the php.ini file can cause the sesssion to fail?` and post the `.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't work with session directly try the following, place it a the top of your script :

```
session_start();
$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
$cnt = $_SESSION['cnt'];
```

then work with the variable instead

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely your 'and' statement.  It should be &&.  The condition is not going to be true.

Comment: wrong, 'and' is ok i see its true as the header function within the condition triggers ok if provided correct credentials in POST

Comment: Yeah but it looks like crap, it doesn't keep to most formal standards.

Comment: learned to use 'and' instead of '&&' in php code because of syntax higlighting habits of codemirror plugin used in my favourite cms

Answer (score 0):

If you're 100% sure the code is all fine and the `PHP.ini` is the problem, based on your comments above. Look at this link at check the settings in the `.ini` http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

Comment: this will most probably be the case, have to check

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that the the first thing you do on every page is to start a session (I recommend calling it once in a header file that you require on all of your sub sites).

So that you have session_start(); everywhere in the system.

Second of all, tighten up your code; make it easier to read. Something like

```
$userName = isset($_POST['userName']) ? $_POST['userName'] : false;
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : false;
$logout = isset($_POST['logout']) ? $_POST['logout'] : false;

$url = '../index.php';

if(!($logout))
{
    if($userName && $password)
    {
        if($userName == $un && $password == $pw)
        {
            $_SESSION['loggedIn']=true;
            $_SESSION['uid']=$Xid;
            $_SESSION['message']="success";
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['loggedIn']=false;
            $_SESSION['message']="fail, incorrect login information.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['loggedIn']=false;
        $_SESSION['message']="fail ; username and password not submitted.";
    }
    header("Location: $url");

}
else
{
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
    header("Location: $url");
}
```

And if you want to display unqiue content depending on whether a user is logged in or not, then you can simply check if the login session is set or not, on each page, instead of modifying the header for that.

Comment: that answer is pretty much beyond the expectations thanks for effort ;) as mentioned I have the session start there and as session works on GET its clear its there and working, yeah? 'bout tightening the code for better reading i did not expect these few lines to be hard to understand. I just hoped somebody finds this problem familiar and tells me code is okay and maybe what to check in the ini or elsewhere, just got anounced it stopped working after apache and php upgrade, sooooo... :)

Comment: hmm have you checked out ob_start? Not sure if it's related but it has solved problems of minein the past that have something to do with sessions.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php
I'm not quite sure what's causing your problem, can you maybe can show us the entire code and the output?

Comment: hi Jonast92 yes the first thing in my code is <?php ob_start(); session_start(); and tried too in opposite order seesion start before ob start.... ob start is a nice "buffer" allowing modifying header /changing session data or sending a redirect header(Location:...) even after output stared as it keeps it buffered and echoes it then later, or on ob_end_flush or on script end/ but it does not help me and even error logs seem not to log anything concerning this

Answer (score 0):

To pass the current session to the next page... I believe is what you are asking...

You are currently not passing the session to the next page and use `session_start()` at the top of the next page.

Change line 4 to:

```php
{ $_SESSION['uid']=$Xid;header('Location: '.$uri.'?'.SID.'&page=welcome'); } // Where "page" is the name of the data you are retrieving
```

Or, you can save the session data to a cookie and then retrieve it on the next page.

You can alternately name the session when you use `session_start("NameHere")` on each page, however if the visitor has recently visited and the session not destroyed, they may see parse errors, if you have them enabled.